# Is initial synthesizable in ASIC?

Tags: verilog, synthesis

I haven't tried to synthesize myself but if someone could help to give a quick answer, that would be highly appreciated.

For a regular RAM, I see people do this in their Verilog, but I am told that initial is not synthesizable in Synopsys Design Compiler and I wonder if there is a difference among tools. Or this is doable just for memory initialization.

```
initial begin
    for (count=0;count<2048;count=count+1) RAM[count]=0;
end
```

This is specifically targeting ASIC instead of FPGA or Xilinx. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of using `initial` block, one can also initialize memory by using `reset` condition in `always` procedural block.

Comment: @sharvil111 can I reside for loop with reset?

Comment: Yes as far as the `for` loop terminating condition is fixed. If you are using SystemVerilog, then one can also use default array assignment `'{default:'0}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it can be used for simulation purposes only. Synopsys Design Compiler does not synthesize `initial` blocks, it throws the following warning instead.

> The statements in initial blocks are ignored.